# Export functionality not working in Zingchart on IIS/SSL website

Tags: asp.net, ssl, webforms, export-to-pdf, zingchart

I made a web application in ASP.Net Web forms with .Net 4.5.2.I am using Zingchart free version to create and export charts.The site is used on https. http is disabled.

The "Export" feature of zingchart works properly on http mode but not when accessed on https. I am unable to export to any format (pdf,png,svg).

What do i need do to get zingchart export working on https??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was seen by someone in Zingchart who asked for the resolution internally keeping me in CC. 
The resolution came as a surprise to me.

First, Zingchart updated the SSL certificate for its export facilitation site Export.Zingchart.com which resolved the issue.

Second, I didn't knew that whenever I export any chart in PDF, PNG or SVG, I was sending the data to the site mentioned above. To resolve this issue, I require to implement my own export server using PhantomJS.

Thanks

Comment: If you've solved the question, I'd suggest accepting your answer or closing the question.